# How to get gaze input position in unity5 using GVr?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am following a tutorial where when the mouse moves over,a cross grid appears.

```
if(Physics.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition),out hit,25.0f)
```

This is what is used in the script. How can I modify this so that I get the position of the GVr reticle instead?

I need to know the position of the Gvr gaze(ie,reticle). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked with GVR but from my experience with Ocullus VR I assume that reticle / gaze is always looking at center of view so you can use `camera` position to get start point for your `raycast`. Like this will give you world point:

```
// use your main camera
Vector3 p = camera.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, camera.nearClipPlane));
```

Remember view port is `(0,0)` at bottom left and `(1,1)` at top right. So you will need `(0.5f,0.5f)` for center of view port and `z` component of input `Vector3` is `nearClipPlane` of your camera. Hope it helps

Comment: okay so, the vector p is the position of the reticle ?  Thanks

Comment: Its position from where you cast the ray.

Comment: @SaranyaAnanthakrishnan please vote up and select it as correct answer to help others :)